# How is a Java ArrayList modified when passed as parameter to function that returns void and modified in function? May be confused on pass-by-value

Tags: java, recursion, arraylist, pass-by-value

I have a block of Java code that modifies an ArrayList by passing the ArrayList into a method, modifying the list in the method, and returns void. I thought that Java's pass-by-value would cause the original ArrayList to not be modified. What am I misunderstanding?

```
public class Question {

    public static void weaveLists(LinkedList<Integer> first, LinkedList<Integer> second, ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> results, LinkedList<Integer> prefix) {
        /* One list is empty. Add the remainder to [a cloned] prefix and
         * store result. */
        if (first.size() == 0 || second.size() == 0) {
            LinkedList<Integer> result = (LinkedList<Integer>) prefix.clone();
            result.addAll(first);
            result.addAll(second);
            results.add(result);
            return;
        }

        /* Recurse with head of first added to the prefix. Removing the
         * head will damage first, so we’ll need to put it back where we
         * found it afterwards. */
        int headFirst = first.removeFirst();
        prefix.addLast(headFirst);
        weaveLists(first, second, results, prefix);
        prefix.removeLast();
        first.addFirst(headFirst);

        /* Do the same thing with second, damaging and then restoring
         * the list.*/
        int headSecond = second.removeFirst();
        prefix.addLast(headSecond);
        weaveLists(first, second, results, prefix);
        prefix.removeLast();    
        second.addFirst(headSecond);
    }

    public static ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> allSequences(TreeNode node) {
        ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>();

        if (node == null) {
            result.add(new LinkedList<Integer>());
            return result;
        } 

        LinkedList<Integer> prefix = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        prefix.add(node.data);

        /* Recurse on left and right subtrees. */
        ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> leftSeq = allSequences(node.left);
        ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> rightSeq = allSequences(node.right);

        /* Weave together each list from the left and right sides. */
        for (LinkedList<Integer> left : leftSeq) {
            for (LinkedList<Integer> right : rightSeq) {
//This is the part I don't understand
                ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>> weaved = new ArrayList<LinkedList<Integer>>();
                weaveLists(left, right, weaved, prefix);
                result.addAll(weaved);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

I would expect that the weaved array would not be modified when the result.addAll(weaved) is called, but weaved array is modified after the call to weaveLists(), even though it returns void.

Comment: This should help: https://javaranch.com/campfire/StoryCups.jsp, https://javaranch.com/campfire/StoryPassBy.jsp.

Comment: "but weaved array is modified after the call to weaveLists(), even though it returns void" return type has nothing to do with how method arguments will be used in method, I am not sure why you think otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You create a `weaved` reference to an `ArrayList` object that stored in memory. When you call `new` operator then a new object allocated in the memory. Then you pass the reference `weaved` to the `weaveLists()` method.
This method have a reference `result`, but this is only a reference that refer to the same object in the memory, because only `new` operator allocate a new memory. So, the `weaveLists()` method modify your original ArrayList. It is a major feature that you should understand, I suggest you to read the difference between **pass-by-value** and **pass-by-reference**.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in short - **you are misunderstanding what does the pass-by-value mean in Java**.

If you pass **an object** (list in this case) and manipulate it's elements without changing it's reference, it is the same object you passed, nothing changed on the object (list) itself, it has the same reference it had when passed to function, but changes do apply to any of the elements being manipulated.

Pass by value in this context only means that if you created a new instance of a given list within the function and then manipulated it - no changes would apply on original list, since that would be observed as a local variable, not the passed one.

Check top answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value) question, or just read some java basics related to pass-by-value. Use [this](https://www.baeldung.com/java-pass-by-value-or-pass-by-reference) blog, or any other that you might like more.

Comment: Actually, I don't think your example of what pass-by-value means is very helpful, since, if the code made a copy and manipulated it, it would not affect the item passed in no matter how it was passed. One way I think of it is that the called method cannot, by design, create a new object and return it as one of the parameters passed in; the only way an object created by the called method can get back to the caller is to return it as the return value of the method.